# Multiple google analytics to track AJAX request

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, google-analytics

I am updating a page on my website using AJAX but for some reason Google Analytics is not registering the page visit. What I need to do so that Google Analytics update the same?

I have checked in stackoverflow for same but all of them are using single tracking ids. But I am not getting how can I use this for multiple tracking?

I have 7 tracking ids: **UA-XXXXXXXX-(1-7)** which I need to update depending on a value returned by my AJAX query.

I am using latest GA code:

```
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');
  ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-X', 'auto');
  ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>
```

What I need to do to track this properly?

Comment: Just confirming, are all 7 IDs being used on the same site (ie. on the same page, but just different on different AJAX page content)?

Comment: @nyuen Yes it is on same page and same site. Only AJAX will change the content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are implementing multiple trackers on the same site, on the same pages, then you need to make sure that you distinguish each tracker and the functions you are calling.

cf. https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/creating-trackers#working_with_multiple_trackers

```
// example
ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-1', 'auto'); // main tracker
ga('send', 'pageview');

// example
ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-2', 'auto', 'tracker2'); // secondary tracker
ga('tracker2.send', 'pageview');
ga('tracker2.set', 'page', 'some/other/page');

// example
ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-2', 'auto', 'tracker3'); // tertiary tracker
ga('tracker3.send', 'pageview');
ga('tracker3.send','event', 'blah, 'bla');

// etc.
```

So for each tracker,  you need to make sure you specify a name (or none for the default), and then when you call the specific method (eg. 'send', 'set', etc.), then you need to include that tracker name.

Comment: Can you confirm, Case will be AJAX will return the tracking id to use. I will use that using ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-1', 'auto'); for first return call.  And then I will create a new tracker if the tracking id is different ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-2', 'auto', 'tracker2'); But what if first or already created tracking id come back? Then what I need to do?

Comment: You only need to create the tracker once per page, but in your case you've only got the one page. So in this case, you just need to create all trackers once on page load, and for whichever tracking is returned in your AJAX, then you need to make sure the right tracker name is used. (Sorry if I'm misinterpreting your question!)

Comment: Okay so in first page load (either ajax or without ajax) as my main ajax call will be send after first basic page load: I will make all tracker using ga('create', '....) and for all 7 ids.
After then in my AJAX response code I will hit ga('send', 'pageview'); ?
Correct?

Comment: Yes, I believe so. So on the first page load, you send the regular pageview `ga('send', 'pageview')`, and then for whatever pages are loaded through AJAX, you do `ga('tracker#.send','pageview')`.